# Counting vowels in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
    print(count)


def countVowels(string):
    vowel=("aeiouAEIOU")
    count=0
    string=input("enter a string:")
    for i in string:
        if i in vowel:
            count +=1
main()
```

Why does it tell me that count is not defined when I try to run it. And I am aware that there are multiple of these question, but I am new to functions and could use the help.

Comment: You don't really need the vowels in uppercase too, in your for statement, just write string.lower() then all characters in the string will be converted to lower case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `count` is a local variable. It is defined only for `countVowels` function. In addition, you only define `countVowels` function, but never run it. So `count` is never created even within that function...

You can do this instead:

```
def main(x):
    print(x)

def countVowels():
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    count = 0
    string = raw_input("enter a string:")
    for i in string:
        if i in vowels:
            count += 1
    return count

main(countVowels())
```

Here `countVowels` returns the count and then you can print it or assign it to a variable or do whatever you want with it. You also had a couple of other errors I fixed on a way... I.e., the function argument `string` is useless as you actually take it as a user input.

On another topic, you can make your count a bit more pythonic:

```
sum(letter in vowel for letter in string)
```

In addition, here I don't see the need to create a whole new function just to print your result... Just do `print(countVowels())` and you're done.

Another improvement would be to care only about lowercase letters, since you don't really distinguish between them:

```
vowels = "aeiou"
string = string.lower()
```

If instead of taking user input you'd like to count vowels in a given word you can do it like this (including improvements outlined above):

```
def countVowels(string):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    string = string.lower()
    return sum(letter in vowel for letter in string)

print(countVowels("some string here"))
```

Comment: so i should print(string,count)?

Comment: -1 Did you even check your code? It obviously overrides some variable, after someone gets rid of your `NameError` (the one you generated by fixing OP's `NameError`).

Comment: @Tadeck Question is not about it. Certainly, you should define a string to make it work. Edited.

Comment: I apologize if i frustrate you by saying im still trying to figure it out. I get an error for main(countVowels(string))__ name'string' is not defined

Comment: @Jake Please see the updated code. It works for me... You don't need a function argument - string is not defined and you don't need it at all..

Comment: @Tadeck I did check my code, and this is the first ever function I have created. Hence the reason Ive searched other programs like this and created my own and still do not know the proper execution/definition of how to program functions even after reading my book.

Comment: @Jake Well, you probably need to re-read it because functions are one of the first things to learn...

Comment: Thank you for the updated code I forgot there isint an automatic refresh. Also I was getting confused because in my book it said write a function for def countVowels(string).And I would really like to know more about functions however it was not the first thing on my professors list.

Comment: @Jake If you take your string from user, you don't need argument to countVowels, just as I showed. Otherwise, you can have countVowels(string), please see the edited answer.

Comment: Downvoters, please comment. This is an accepted answer which does work. If there is something wrong - comment and let me know. Improve it, not just criticize it.

Comment: @Jake Can you please let me know why you've unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Because count has been defined within countVowels. You should probably make that function do the counting and then return the count, and ask for the input somewhere else:

```
import re

def count_vowels(string):
    vowels = re.findall('[aeiou]', string, re.IGNORECASE)
    return len(vowels)

string = input("Enter a string:")
print count_vowels(string)
```

Comment: Maybe `re` module is an overkill here. You only need to count letters matching specific critieria, no need for regular expressions (if you will prove it to be faster, I will upvote).

Comment: It may be overkill, I have not used re or findall yet.

Comment: re.finall may not be faster (I haven't benchmarked it), but I think the resulting code is much clearer and simpler

Comment: I have "timeit". The difference in performance between using re vs. simple loop is minimal (32 - 37) 10^-6s.