# Counting number of vowels in a string in Python

Tags: python

Okay so what I did was

```
def countvowels(st):
    result=st.count("a")+st.count("A")+st.count("e")+st.count("E")+st.count("i")+st.count("I")+st.count("o")+st.count("O")+st.count("u")+st.count("U")
    return result
```

This works(I'm aware indentation might be wrong in this post, but the way I have it indented in python, it works).

Is there a better way to do this? Using for loops?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237791/counting-vowels-in-python

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
def countvowels(st):
  return len ([c for c in st if c.lower() in 'aeiou'])
```

Comment: `sum(c.lower() in 'aeiou' for c in st)` saves making a temporary list

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely better ways. Here's one.

```
   def countvowels(s):
      s = s.lower()
      return sum(s.count(v) for v in "aeiou")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using list comprehension

```
def countvowels(w):
    vowels= "aAiIeEoOuU"
    return len([i for i in list(w) if i in list(vowels)])
```

Comment: You don't need the `list` constructors. Strings are iterable in python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex pattern to do this easily. But it looks to me, that you want to do it without. So here is some code to do so:

```
string = "This is a test for vowel counting"
print [(i,string.count(i)) for i in list("AaEeIiOoUu")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in various ways, first look in google before asking, i had copy pasted 2 of them

```
def countvowels(string):
    num_vowels=0
    for char in string:
        if char in "aeiouAEIOU":
           num_vowels = num_vowels+1
    return num_vowels
```

---

```
data = raw_input("Please type a sentence: ")
vowels = "aeiou"
for v in vowels:
    print v, data.lower().count(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `Counter` from `collections` (only available from Python 2.7+) as shown below . It'll show how many times each letter has been repeated.

```
from collections import Counter
st = raw_input("Enter the string")
print Counter(st)
```

But you want vowels specifically then try this.

```
import re

def count_vowels(string):
    vowels = re.findall('[aeiou]', string, re.IGNORECASE)
    return len(vowels)

st = input("Enter a string:")
print count_vowels(st)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using map:

```
phrase=list("This is a test for vowel counting")
base="AaEeIiOoUu"
def c(b):
    print b+":",phrase.count(b)
map(c,base)
```